Update an on-screen counter during a For Loop
I'have a Page (Counter_Page) where i need to see a Label whith a counter that increment yourself.
All works good but i See only the end of the counter, the last message !!!
In a For Loop from 0 to 9 i see only the Label 'Counter 9'
I'have used a Binding
XAML Code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="UpKeepAPP.Pagine.Counter_Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding p_Counter_Message}"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

            <Button x:Name="Button_Counter" 
                    Clicked="Button_Counter_Clicked"
                    Text="Start Counter"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

Counter_Page Code
  public partial class Counter_Page : ContentPage
    {

        Counter_VM The_Counter = new Counter_VM();


        public Counter_Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = The_Counter;
        }


        private void Button_Counter_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++)
            {
                The_Counter.p_Counter_Message = $"Counter {indice}";
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }

Counter_VM Code
 public class Counter_VM  : BaseViewModel

    {
        string m_Counter_Message = "";

        public string p_Counter_Message
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Counter_Message;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Counter_Message = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }

(BaseViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChange)
Can anyone help me ?? Thank's

Never use Thread.Sleep for these things, it will keep your thread asleep and doing that to your MainThread can block your app until the time is over.
When to use Task.Delay, when to use Thread.Sleep?
I would change your code to this and it should fix the issue
private async void Button_Counter_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int indice = 0; indice < 10; indice++)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> The_Counter.p_Counter_Message = $"Counter {indice}");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }

Not sure why you are doing what you are doing here but hope it helps!
